# Error in map function reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having an error with the map function. I dont know what might be the reason but it says this.state.rooms.map is not a function. I have fetched the data from api and pushed into an empty list . The list is successfully updated with the contents but could not apply map function on it.

**Here's my code**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


export default class RoomList extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { rooms: [] }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        console.log('componentDidMount');
        this.loadRoomFromServer();
    }

    loadRoomFromServer(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'/api/v1/rental/',
            dataType:'json',
            success: (data) => {
                this.setState({rooms: data});
              },
              error: (xhr, status, err) => {
                console.error(url, status, err.toString());
              }
            });
    }

    render(){
        console.log('rooms',this.state.rooms);
        let listOfRoom = this.state.rooms.map((room)=>{
            return(
                    <Room key={room.id} name={room.listingName} price={room.price} number={room.room} />
                )
        });
        return(
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <div className="row">
                            { listOfRoom }
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
    }
}

class Room extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
                <div className="col-md-4">
                    <h2>{this.props.name}</h2>
                    <p>{this.props.price}</p>
                    <p>{this.props.number}</p>
                </div>
            )
    }
}
```

what i get on the console is

room []

componentDidMount

room Object {amenities: "Kitchen, Cable", city: "city", email: "tushant@gmail.com", listingName: "tushant", ownerName: "tushant"…}

Uncaught TypeError: this.state.rooms.map is not a function

Comment: could you add to your question result of `console.log(Array.isArray(this.state.rooms))` ? Because seems that `this.state.rooms` is `Object` not `Array`

Comment: So the `Object {amenities: "Kitchen, ...}` is the result of `console.log(this.state.rooms)`? Then here's the problem, `this.state.rooms` is an Object (representing a single room I guess), not an Array. If you only expect a single room from the API then either `this.setState({rooms: [ data ]});` (replace the current array) or `this.setState({rooms: this.state.rooms.puch(data)});` (to append the room), or fix your API to return arrays.

Comment: yes object is the result of this.state.rooms . I want to fetch all the room from the API but i could only fetch one room. I did this.setState({rooms:[data]}). What should be done inorder to fetch all the room from an api?

Comment: @Tushant maybe URL for ajax should looks like this `/api/v1/rentals` ? But we can't answer on this question because we have not seen your backend API

Comment: my bad i forgot to change that . I was tweaking my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @sfletche mentioned `map` function for arrays only.
change your `success` callback to

```
success: (data) => {
    this.setState({rooms: data.objects});
 },
 error: (xhr, status, err) => {
    console.error(url, status, err.toString());
  }
});
```

Comment: This way i could fetch only 1 room from an api as i want to fetch all the room from an api.

Comment: the issue is from the api (backend) not from frontend you need to make sure you are sending array of rooms, if you can post your API response

Comment: yes now i get such http://imgur.com/VZEkPMZ . I am getting all the room now. I forgot to change my url.

Comment: but nothing is rendered in my template.

Comment: if you can post your response here, and console.log in `success` callback

Comment: Your `rooms` inside `objects` so you need to set 
this.setState({rooms: data[0].objects});

Comment: sorry it said Cannot read property 'objects' of undefined . When i did this.setState({ rooms: data.objects }); it gave me the result that i wanted. Thanks for your help and thanks i got to learn from you .

Comment: tried to help:), if you can vote up to my answer or set as correct answer

Comment: Can you edit setState in your answer so i can mark this as answered ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `map` function for objects, only arrays.

Your second output of `rooms` shows the answer

```
room Object {amenities: "Kitchen, Cable", city: "city", email: 
"tushant@gmail.com", listingName: "tushant", ownerName: "tushant"…}
```

`rooms` is now an object and the `map` function is specific to arrays.